# simple afterSave method doesn't work in Yii

Tags: php, mysql, activerecord, yii

I wanna update a field in inserted raw by `afterSave` method,so I develop following code in Driver Model

```
protected function afterSave() {
        parent::afterSave();
        if ($this->isNewRecord) {
            $newid = self::newid($this->id);
            $this->updateByPk($this->id, new CDbCriteria(array('condition'=>'driverid = :driverid', 'params'=>array('driverid'=>  $newid))));
        }
}
```

and in Controller the method which crud made:

```
public function actionCreate()
{
    $model=new Driver;

    // Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed
    // $this->performAjaxValidation($model);

    if(isset($_POST['Driver']))
    {
        $model->attributes=$_POST['Driver'];
        if($model->save())
            $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->id));
    }

    $this->render('create',array(
        'model'=>$model,
    ));
}
```

### why after save doesn't work?

edit:

```
    private static function CheckNumber($number) {
        $array = array(10);
        for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++)
            $array[$i] = 0;
        do {
            $array[$number % 10]++;
            $number /= 10;
        } while ((int) ($number / 10 ) != 0);
        $array[$number]++;

        for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++)
            if ($array[$i] > 1)
                return false;
        return true;
    }

public static function newid($id) {
    while (self::CheckNumber($id) == FALSE) {
        $id++;
    }
    return $id;
}
```

Comment: Please show self::newid method

Answer (score 5):

Your updateByPk is messed up..

[Check Documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord#updateByPk-detail)

As its not clear what you want to do..So I am presuming you want to update driver_id value by result of `self::newid($this->id);` of just inserted row..

what you should do is:

```
protected function afterSave() {
    parent::afterSave();
    if ($this->isNewRecord) {
        $newid = self::newid($this->id);
        $this->driverid = $new_id;
        $this->isNewRecord = false;
        $this->saveAttributes(array('driverid'));
    }
}
```

And yeah you are right about usage of `afterSave()`

> isNewRecord is true even after new record is created, but after first
>   time, it will be false always..

[From Yii Forum said By Qiang Himself..](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/2982-ar-isnewrecord-and-aftersave/)

Comment: I got following error by your code:The active record cannot be updated because it is new.

Comment: I test it to, got following error:
CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '345' for key 'PRIMARY'. The SQL statement executed was:

Comment: INSERT INTO `driver` (`name`, `fathername`, `nationalcode`, `birthdaycity`, `birthday`, `education`, `cellphone`, `group`, `dltype`, `workid`, `company`, `worklocation`, `bustype`, `experienceyear`, `practical_class_day_time`, `practical_class_enter_time`, `practical_class_exit_time`, `certificatetime`, `computerskill`, `gameskill`, `score1`, `score2`, `score3`, `scoretype`, `address`, `phone`, `imgadd`, `id`, `driverid`) VALUES (:yp0, :yp1, :yp2, :yp3, :yp4, :yp5, :yp6, :yp7, :yp8, :yp9, :yp10, :yp11, :yp12, :yp13, :yp14, :yp15, :yp16, :yp17, :yp18, :yp19, :yp20, :yp21, :yp22,

Comment: try now..Inspired from http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/21985-calling-save-within-aftersave/

Answer (score 1):

As rightly pointed out by Rajat, your `updateByPk();` is incorrect. You can instead use this line, to update the `driverid` field of the newly created record:

```
$this->updateByPk($this->id,array('driverid'=>$newid));
```

So your entire `afterSave()` becomes this:

```
protected function afterSave() {
    parent::afterSave();
    if ($this->isNewRecord) {
        $newid = self::newid($this->id);
        $this->updateByPk($this->id,array('driverid'=>$newid));
    }
}
```

`saveAttributes()` ultimately calls `updateByPk()`.

Comment: +1 This solution allows an update without polluting the isNewRecord property

Answer (score 0):

The insert method in "CActiveRecord" sets the "isNewRecord" property as "false" if the insertion is done successfully.

Therefore the "if ($this->isNewRecord)" condition in your afterSave method is always false and the program  will never execute the updateByPk method inside this condition. That's why your afterSave won't work.

Answer (score 0):

```
public function afterSave(){
        if($this->isNewRecord) {
            $transaction_entry = new TransactionEntry;
            $transaction_entry->branch_id = 1;
            $transaction_entry->date_of_transaction = $this->bill_date;
            $transaction_entry->account_category_id = 1;
            $transaction_entry->description = $this->student->admission_no ."-".$this->course->course_name."-".$this->fee_month."/".$this->fee_year;
            $transaction_entry->amount = $this->total_amount;
            $transaction_entry->save();
        }
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, as this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!